# React-redux dispatch triggers action creator but reducer is not called

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, dispatch

I am trying using modules redux, react-redux to switch the current view shown in an app, but dispatching my action creator does not call the reducer. I have used console messages to show that the corresponding reducer gets called during initialization, the action creater gets called when dispatched, but the action creator does not trigger the reducer.

client/src/App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';

// actions
const SET_VIEW = 'SET_VIEW';

const setView = (view) => {
  console.log(view);
  return { type: SET_VIEW, view };
};

// views
const HOME_VIEW = 'HOME';
const OTHER_VIEW = 'OTHER';

//reducers

const initialState = {
  view: HOME_VIEW,
};

const viewReducer = function (state, action) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(action));
  if (action.type === SET_VIEW) {
    if (action.view === HOME_VIEW) {
      return HOME_VIEW;
    }
    if (action.view === OTHER_VIEW) {
      return OTHER_VIEW;
    }
  }
  return HOME_VIEW;
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  view: viewReducer,
});

// selectors
const getView = (state) => state.view;

//store
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);

function Main({ view }) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: '250px',
        display: 'block',
        margin: 'auto',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: '1px',
      }}
    >
      {view === HOME_VIEW && <HomeViewConnected />}
      {view === OTHER_VIEW && <OtherView />}
    </div>
  );
}

const MainConnected = connect(
  (state) => ({
    view: getView(state),
  }),
  null
)(Main);

function HomeView() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setView(OTHER_VIEW)}>View Other</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const HomeViewConnected = connect(null, (dispatch) => ({
  setView: (value) => dispatch(setView(value)),
}))(HomeView);

class OtherView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Other</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainConnected />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My console shows that the reducer gets called three times with INIT actions when the page loads. Upon pushing the 'Other' button, the message from the action creator is printed, but not the message from the reducer.

I have tried restarting the dev server.
Askers of similar articles seem to be usually misusing dispatch. I think I'm using dispatch correctly because I compare to the redux code in Tsonev's wonderful "React in Patterns."
https://github.com/krasimir/react-in-patterns/blob/master/code/redux/src/app.jsx

Edited to fix atrocious formatting.

Comment: Have you considered the fact the article you are using is almost 5 years old? That is like two centuries in React/Redux time. Consider updating your references.

Comment: Thank you for this context. The current page for the connect function on which I rely says it should still work in the current version, but I'll try the recommended hooks API instead and get back. https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Answer (score 0):

Randy Casburn's observation solved my problem.

I don't know why connect() isnt working since it is supposed to for react-redux 8.x, but switching to the recommended hooks API made my action creator, setView, correctly trigger the reducer, viewReducer.
https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Specifically, redefining HomeViewConnected to the following makes it work.

```
const HomeViewConnected = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(setView(OTHER_VIEW))} >View Other</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Thanks Randy!